# Which Snake fields can be played infinitely long?

Tags: graph-theory, recreational-mathematics

[Snake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_(video_game)) is a very old game for phones. Its a 'real time game', that means you have to make decisions fast. The rules are:

- You are a snake.
- You can move to the left, to the right or go straight ahead.
- Your length is $n$ at the beginning, but there are fruits which make you longer.
- The more fruits you eat, the more points you get. But with each fruit you eat, you get longer.
- If you crash into a wall / yourself, the game is over.
- The game field is a $n \times m$ grid, but there might be obstacles on the grid. You could also eventually go thorugh the borders of the game (so: from top to bottom, from left to right) or not (there are different 'maps')

You can [play snake here](http://playsnake.org/) if you don't know it.

I am now interested in what happens when your length is equal to the number of free cells on the board. Can you play it infinitely long?

### My ideas

I think this is similar to the *seven bridges of Königsberg* except that you don't want to visit all bridiges exactly once, but all isles exactly once and get back to the isle you started with. However, I don't know if there is a similar (solved) problem. So the question how to decide if a map can be played infinitely long remains.

Comment: The largest length that snake can have is equal to the number of cells in the grid

Comment: @Jasser: Not always. Think of a grid which is U-shaped and you start not at one end. Obviously it is not possible there. And I am sure there are other (non-trivial) grids where it is not possible.

Comment: I commented according to your question "nxm" grid

Comment: @Jasser: n = 1, m = 5, starting point (0, 3).

Answer (score 1):

What is searched is a [Hamiltonian path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path): Every free grid cell can be mapped to a vertex and every "neighboring" relationship can be mapped to an edge. Then every cell should be visited exactly once.

Finding a Hamiltonian path in an arbitrary Graph is NP-Complete. However, those graphs are not arbitrary. Every vertex has at most 4 edges. (I am not sure if this is of any use)

Comment: I think it's actually a Hamiltonian cycle that’s required. To keep playing when your length is the size of the board, your head needs to move to the cell that your tail vacates.